# How should the Microsoft Azure Media Services Channel ID be formatted when using its Rest API?

Tags: azure, uri, azure-media-services

I've been reading through the Microsoft Azure [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/media/operations/channel#start_channels) idealizing how one should format the strings when making calls to Microsoft Azure Media Services REST API for Channels.  The documentation reads that the format should be the following:

```
https://<accountname>.restv2.<location>.media.azure.net/api/Channels
```

Therefore as I understand it, this would need to be changed to read:

```
https://genericAccountName.restv2.eastus.media.azure.net/api/Channels(‘genericChannelName’)
```

My question is, would I need to get rid of any quotes or parenthesis in the URI for accessing the Channels API?

Comment: Consider installing Postman, and using the documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/previous/media-rest-apis-with-postman to make REST calls. If this doesn't help, please let us know and we'll follow up. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example from the doc:

POST https://testrest.cloudapp.net/api/Channels('nb:chid:UUID:2c30f424-ab90-40c6-ba41-52a993e9d393')/Start HTTP/1.1

so you need ' around the id name.